# drupal display submenu when parent has been selected

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, menu

I've have a menu structure that has a depth of 3 levels on a drupal 6 CMS.

When I click on a level 1 that has children, the level 2 menu items display fine.  If the level 2 has children, it is not showing the level 3.

If I check the expanded box the level 3 is displayed however, it displays all the time irrespective of the level 2 that has been selected.  It seems to display whenever it's parent level 1 is selected.

For further information, the menu items are a mixture of custom links & content links.  i.e. Links I've enetered manually when creating the menu and others generated by when creating a node or view display.

All I want is to show the children if there are any for the selected parent.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: I managed to figure out a work around although it does not really address my issue but resolves my problem.

Basically I had problems with manually creating a link to a view display, so I create the menu link from the view display itself and then moved the menu item via the menu manager.

Answer (score 0):

In the menu settings you should play around with a setting called "expanded". See /admin/build/menu-customize/primary-links and play around with the expanded setting.

If you expand a menu item then all its children are displayed in the block, otherwise only when you click on the parent item do the children get displayed.

You can have some more control on menu's in blocks by checking out http://drupal.org/project/menu_block